# How to add cookie to header through Django Channels?

Tags: django, react-native, authentication, websocket, django-channels

In my frontend, I have the following configuration. Authentication is manual because react native fails at having persistent sessions:

```
...
const authLink = setContext(request =>
  storage.getCookie().then(cookie => ({
    // Before the request is sent: set cookie header
    headers: {
      cookie,
    },
    credentials: 'omit', // set cookies manually
  }))
)

const setTokenLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // Send the request to the server
  return forward(operation).map(response => {
    // After response is returned: store cookie in local storage
    const context = operation.getContext()
    const {
      response: { headers },
    } = context

    if (headers) {
      storage.setCookie(headers.get('set-cookie'))
    }

    return response
  })
})
storage.getCookie().then(cookie => console.log(cookie))
// console.log('cookie', storage.getCookie().then(cookie => {cookie}))

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: `${domainApi}/graphql/`,
})

const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(
  domainWs,
  {
    lazy: true,
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: storage.getCookie(),
    },
  })
)
...
```

Yet this seems to affect websockets, because at the backend, the headers don't contain the cookie.

```
class GraphqlSubcriptionConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def __init__(self, scope):
        super().__init__(scope)
        self.subscriptions = {}
        self.groups = {}

    def websocket_connect(self, message):
        self.send({"type": "websocket.accept", "subprotocol": "graphql-ws"})

    def websocket_disconnect(self, message):
        for group in self.groups.keys():
            group_discard = async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)
            group_discard(f"django.{group}", self.channel_name)

        self.send({"type": "websocket.close", "code": 1000})
        raise StopConsumer()

    def websocket_receive(self, message):
        request = json.loads(message["text"])
        id = request.get("id")

        if request["type"] == "connection_init":
            return

        elif request["type"] == "start":
            print("scope user:", self.scope["user"]) //returns AnonymousUser
            print("scope headers:", self.scope["headers"]) //returns headers without the cookie
...
```

With this configuration I get

```
{'type': 'websocket.receive', 'text': '{"type":"connection_init","payload":{"authToken":{"_40":0,"_65":1,"_55":"sessionid=bci028bzn1cgxyuynvb7fjevc5ynqdil","_72":null}}}'}
```

at every first message with type `connection_init`. So I was wondering if there was a way to manually insert the cookie in django (possibly within `if request["type"] == "connection_init":`) into the scope, so that subsequent messages of type `start` contain the cookie.

Any small tip/hint helps.

Answer (score 0):

To set a cookie within your server's handshake response (tested with `channels==2.3.1`):

```
def connect(self):  # connect method of your WebsocketConsumer
    # called on connection
    headers = {}
    headers['Set-Cookie'] = 'myCookie=myValue'
    self.accept(subprotocol=(None, headers))
```

Once a connection is established, there is no way to send cookies from the server to the user agent through the `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header. Thats because it is an open TCP socket and the protocol is no longer HTTP.

`Django Channels` uses `autobahn` under the hood. https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/9e68328df3c23ca3eee67017404235024f265693/autobahn/websocket/types.py#L285